# surface plot with only z data from file, while x and y coordinates to be calculated

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to create a surface plot from a large set of *z* data in a text file.

For the sake of minimum file size and since the *z* values are located on a regular rectangular mesh, the *x* and *y* coordinates are not stored in the file, but should be calculated on-the-fly while reading the *z* data from the file.

Consider the following minimal example with *inline* data (taken from the `pgfplots` manual):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
  \addplot3[surf,mesh/rows=3] coordinates {
    (0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0) (0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5) (0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How do I have to modify the example such that it can create the same result from an *external* data file with the following format (all *z* values on a single input line; more input lines to follow, each representing another time step):

```
% input.dat
0 0 0 0 0 0.6 0.7 0.5 0 0.7 0.8 0.5
```

Is this possible out-of-the-box at all, or do I have to pre-process the data by an external program or script?

Comment: You can use `\addplot3[...] table[x expr=..., y expr=...,z = ...]` but the input must be column readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the only way to do the necessary pre-processing.  You could also use `xstring` or `pgfplotstable`.

Note: the blank in `\parse` after `#1` is important.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.12}

\newcommand{\somelist}{}% reserve global name

\begin{document}

\bgroup% use local names and registers
  \countdef\row=1
  \countdef\column=2
% copy file to \data
  \newread\fid
  \openin\fid=test.dat % contains only 0 0 0 0 0 0.6 0.7 0.5 0 0.7 0.8 0.5
  \read\fid to\data% reads one line from file
  \closein\fid
% recursive macro, #1 = text to next blank (each interation)
  \def\parse#1 {\xdef\somelist{\somelist(\the\row,\the\column,#1)}
    \advance\row by 1
    \ifnum\row>3\relax
      \row=0
      \advance\column by 1
    \fi
    \ifnum\column>2\else\expandafter\parse\fi}
% format data to \somelist
  \xdef\somelist{}
  \row=0
  \column=0
  \expandafter\parse\data
\egroup

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
  \addplot3[surf,mesh/rows=3] coordinates{\somelist};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you have comment lines, you will need to read/skip them manually.