# Surface plot from z data only

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot a meshed surface from a file that contains z data only, arranged in a matrix. The idea is to plot the z data versus x index and y index. Is there an easy way to do that, or do I have to resort to pre-processing of the data file?

(I searched, unsuccessfully, in `pgfplots` manual and several StackExchange questions.)

Example dummy data:

```
CSV data file `data.txt'
M1,M2,M3,M4
0,0,0,0
3.466,2.058,0,0
4.262,2.976,0.001,0
3.822,3.168,0.006,0.008
2.953,2.936,0.019,0.063
2.065,2.492,0.046,0.265
1.332,1.977,0.092,0.734
0.797,1.478,0.164,1.508
```

MNWE (for minimal non-working example ^^):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.txt}\csvdata
   \begin{axis}
      \addplot3[surf] table[x expr=\coordindex,y expr={SOME COLUMN INDEX?}] {\csvdata};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282294/surface-plot-with-only-z-data-from-file-while-x-and-y-coordinates-to-be-calcula?rq=1

Comment: @Superuser27: in that thread the data is not arranged in the same way. Changing the parsing in the answer would quite complex (at least for me).

Comment: I guess that is not possible right how. Please have a look at the [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/76/) (of mine) to achieve exactly this. There you can also find a list o similar questions (I am aware of) here on TeX.SX.

Comment: Ok, I'll reshape my data then! Thanks Stefan.